# CKEditor > IE > resizable frame within contentEditable area, how to disable it?

Tags: internet-explorer, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Please see attached :)

[image: how to disable the resizable frame within]

Actually, not only [ck-editor](http://ckeditor.com/demo), all WYSIWYG editors caused this issue, how to disable that? which wrapped with a resizable frame...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please remove all `height`,`max-height`,`width` and `max-width` stylesheets for contentEditable element.

Comment: BIG THANKS, you did me a gigantic favor!!